# Magento 2.2 HTML; how to change a clickable text into a text with selection boxes?

Tags: magento2, html, checkbox

I was wondering how to change the following:

```
<li class="link">
<a href="https://some-url.com">Some Text</a>
</li>
```

In a way that I can have a text with a squared box, so that when I click on the box, I am redirected to the same url specified in the  tag. If I click on the text, the box should be selected as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" onclick="location.href = 'https://some-url.com';">
  <a id="linkid" href="https://some-url.com">SomeText</a>
```

JQ:

```
$('#linkid').click(
  function() {
    $('#mycheckbox').prop('checked', true);
  }
);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jav1jkea/22/)

Comment: Hi Jurgis; I meant something like this: https://i2.wp.com/www.cssscript.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/tastySelect.png?zoom=2&fit=505%2C386&ssl=1

Comment: @JulianMurillo I updated my answer

Comment: Hi Jurgis; Thanks for your help; I have another question: how to adjust it in a way that the checkbox would redirect to the url in the same browser window (and not in a new one)?

Comment: you remove `target="_blank"` from the `input` and `a` tags ;)

Comment: @JulianMurillo I updated my answer